# how to put a variable in the image source in C# like we do in php

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

how to put a variable in the image source in C#  like we do in php ">

```
var image = "image1.jpg"; //suppose
label.Text = "<asp:Image ID='Image2' src='images/" + image + '"/>";
```

Comment: sorry for the mistakes, i am new in this

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly clear what you want to do: `<asp:Image />` is a server tag which you should place on your webForm.aspx. If you assign the tag to the label, it will be HTML encoded and not display the image

You could do the following on the .aspx page:

```
<asp:Image id="Image2" ImageUrl="images/<%= image %>" runat="server" />
```

Or set the image url in the code behind:

```
Image2.ImageUrl = "images/" + image;
```

Comment: so we can send image url value from .cs to .aspx file?

Comment: yes, both ways work. You give the server control an Id (like Image2), then you can access it from the .cs or you can access a protected property (like image) on the aspx.

Comment: i got the idea now, thanks for helping, us newbies :)